# Is it possible to add attributes in Virtuemart 3?

Tags: joomla-2.5, virtuemart

Is it possible to add attributes to products in Virtuemart 3?

For example, a pizza would have an attribute could "Extra Topping". The user can choose what topping they want from a drop down list, such as "extra cheese" or "peppers".

This was possible in Virtuemart 1, so is it possible in VM3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reasonably sure that the newer VM uses Custom Fields to create Product Attributes.  I haven't done it myself with VM3, but [How to create the VM custom fields](https://www.gavick.com/documentation/supported-third-party-extensions-for-joomla/virtuemart-e-commerce-component/how-to-add-attributes-in-virtuemart) walks through it pretty well.

Comment: I've worked out how to do them individually. However I want to know how to do them in bulk. On VM1 I went into the database and copy and pasted the code. However on this one all fields are stored seperately and look like it will take a long time as I will be entering sometimes over 100 attributes.

Comment: I found an extension for adding them in bulk more easily